# Spaces in wordcloud

Tags: r, word-cloud

I currently use wordle for many artsy uses of the word cloud.  I think that R's word cloud, potentially, has better control.

*1)  How do you keep a word capitalized in the word cloud? [SOLVED]*

**2)  How do keep two words as one chunk in the wordcloud? (wordle uses the ~ operator to accomplish this, R's word cloud merely prints the ~ as is) [For instance where there's a ~ between "to" and "be" I'd like a space in the word cloud]**

```
require(wordcloud)

y<-c("the", "the", "the", "tree", "tree", "tree", "tree", "tree", 
"tree", "tree", "tree", "tree", "tree", "Wants", "Wants", "Wants", 
"Wants", "Wants", "Wants", "Wants", "Wants", "Wants", "Wants", 
"Wants", "Wants", "to~be", "to~be", "to~be", "to~be", "to~be", 
"to~be", "to~be", "to~be", "to~be", "to~be", "to~be", "to~be", 
"to~be", "to~be", "to~be", "to~be", "to~be", "to~be", "to~be", 
"to~be", "when", "when", "when", "when", "when", "familiar", "familiar", 
"familiar", "familiar", "familiar", "familiar", "familiar", "familiar", 
"familiar", "familiar", "familiar", "familiar", "familiar", "familiar", 
"familiar", "familiar", "familiar", "familiar", "familiar", "familiar", 
"leggings", "leggings", "leggings", "leggings", "leggings", "leggings", 
"leggings", "leggings", "leggings", "leggings")

wordcloud(names(table(y)), table(y))
```

Comment: Your original code was reproducible, and I based my answer on that.  Your edit is no longer reproducible, and my answer no longer makes sense.

Comment: @Andrie  Sorry some of that was custom functions that I deleted for future reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You asked two questions:

1. You can control the capitalisation (or not) by specifying a control argument to `TermDocumentMatrix`
2. No doubt there is an argument somewhere to control the `~`, but here is an easy workaround:  Use `gsub` to change `~` to white space in the step just before plotting.

Some code:

```
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(y))
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus, control=list(tolower=FALSE)) ## Edit 1

m <- as.matrix(tdm)
v <- sort(rowSums(m), decreasing = TRUE)
d <- data.frame(word = names(v), freq = v)
d$word <- gsub("~", " ", d$word) ## Edit 2

wordcloud(d$word, d$freq)
```

[image]

Comment: This was an easy fix I was trying to approach it using the tm package which was unnecessary.  Thanks.