# Add date and time to wordcloud plot

Tags: r, text, text-mining, word-cloud

I am running a loop all day and during its execution, it saves different wordcloud graphs. I need to include or add the time in the graph bottom, footnote or even subtitle.

Here is a basic example of how my code is structured:

```
jpeg(paste("C:/Users/,
i,format(Sys.time(), "_%d-%m-%y %H-%M"), ".jpg", sep=""),
width=5, height=5, units="in",  res=1300)

w=wordcloud(dm$word, dm$freq, min.freq=25, random.order = F, 
colors = sample(colors()[3:79]))
print(w)
dev.off()
```

I did try with

```
title(paste(Sys.time()))
```

but didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to adapt this code:

```
library("tm")
library("wordcloud")
x<-"Nel mezzo del cammin di nostra vita mi ritrovai per una selva oscura, ché la diritta via era smarrita."

x<-unlist( strsplit(gsub("[[:punct:]]", '', x), "\ ")) 

layout(matrix(c(1, 2), nrow=2), heights=c(1, 4))
par(mar=rep(0, 4))
plot.new()
text(x=0.5, y=0.5, Sys.time())
wordcloud(x, main="Title")
```

[image]
Example adapted from this previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15224913/r-add-title-to-wordcloud-graphics-png)

Comment: Thanks! work fine, but dont show the time. Do you know how solve it?